# Programmatically tap UIButton not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPad app using XCode 4.6, Storyboards, iOS 6.2. I looked at SO and Google, but nothing about **when** to send the message to the button.

I am trying to save some data to CoreData when the user leaves a "scene" but it's not working. 
Here is the code:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated  {

     [bSavePreferences sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

-bSavePreferences is in the same class as viewWillDisappear, but it never gets called. Why?

**UPDATE:  I should have mentioned that I am using a UITabBarController to control which page is selected.**

Comment: Why are you triggering an action through an event instead of just invoking the IBAction method directly?

Comment: Ditto what BenM said.  My guess is that by the time the OS sends the "actions", the view controller has already been marked as disappeared and therefore the button is considered hidden and/or disabled.

Comment: Hi Michael... so, if I want to save the data when the user leaves the page/scene, where is the place to put the -sendActionsForControlEvents so it get's executed?

Comment: Ben M: please move your comment to an Answer; I removed the IBAction, and just made it a plain ol' method... works like a champ!  Thanks everybody!  I appreciate it... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things...

1. You shouldn't be invoking an action this way. You should just call the IBAction method directly to do the saving.
2. You need to call [super viewWillDisappear:animated] at some point when implementing viewWillDisappear.
3. As for the root problem, viewWillDisappear is called in response to the view being removed from the view hierarchy. It's possible that the UIButton would no longer be able to receive events at this point. I encourage you to look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear%3a).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods:

One way is to add a target action to your button:

```
 [myButton addTarget:self 
         action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The second option is to use IBActions:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed { NSLog@"press"; }
```

Make sure you wire your outlets correctly!